# How can I display the results of arithetics operations in my calculator?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Currently, I am doing a calculator. I have run into some problems trying to get it to display the result. So far I have gotten it to store the numbers clicked into separate variables, but I can't get the correct result to display.

```js
let numIni = "";
let numSub = "";
let op = "";
let calcResult = false;
//const text = display.innerText;
let result = 0;
clr();


//basic addition
function addition(numIni, numSub) {
  return parseFloat(numIni) + parseFloat(numSub);

}

//basic subtraction
function subtraction(numIni, numIni) {
  parseFloat(numIni) - parseFloat(numIni);
}

//basic Multiplication
function multiply(numIni, numIni) {
  parseFloat(numIni) * parseFloat(numIni);
}

//basic division
function divide(numIni, numIni) {
  parseFloat(numIni) / parseFloat(numIni);
}

//operator function
function operate(op) {
  let result;
  switch (op) {
    case "+":
      result = addition(numIni, numSub);
      break;
    case "-":
      result = subtraction(numIni, numIni);
      break;
    case "*":
      result = multiply(numIni, numIni);
      break;
    case "/":
      if (numSub == 0) {
        return "Can't do that";
      } else {
        result = divide(numIni, numIni);
      }
    default:
      return "Null";
  }
}
//button display functions
function disNum(val) {
  if (numIni == "") {
    parseFloat(document.getElementById("display").value += val);
    numIni = parseFloat(val);
  } else {
    parseFloat(document.getElementById("display").value += val);
    numSub = parseFloat(val);
  }

}

function disOp(val) {
  document.getElementById("display").value += val;
  return op = val;
}

function clr() {
  return document.getElementById("display").value = "";
}

function equal() {
  operate(numIni, numSub);
  document.getElementById("display").value = result;
}
```

```html
<head>Calc</head>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="display">
</div>

<input type="button" value="0" onClick="disNum('0')">
<input type="button" value="1" onClick="disNum('1')">
<input type="button" value="2" onClick="disNum('2')">
<input type="button" value="3" onClick="disNum('3')">
<input type="button" value="4" onClick="disNum('4')">
<input type="button" value="5" onClick="disNum('5')">
<input type="button" value="6" onClick="disNum('6')">
<input type="button" value="7" onClick="disNum('7')">
<input type="button" value="8" onClick="disNum('8')">
<input type="button" value="9" onClick="disNum('9')">
<input type="button" value="+" onClick="disOp('+')">
<input type="button" value="-" onClick="disOp('-')">
<input type="button" value="*" onClick="disOp('*')">
<input type="button" value="/" onClick="disOp('/')">
<input type="button" value="=" onClick="equal()">
<input type="button" value="Clr" onClick="clr()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a new input to store last result to hold *numIni* and *previous operator*. I've removed almost all variables from global scope to avoid unwanted changes.

Everytime that operator is clicked, check if there's previous result and operator, then get *numSub* from display input, do the math and save result, along with current operator if any.

I've tested it, but maybe there'll be some bugs.

```js
let display = document.querySelector('#display');
let res = document.querySelector('#result');
clr();

//basic addition
function addition(numIni, numSub) {
  return parseFloat(numIni) + parseFloat(numSub);
}

//basic subtraction
function subtraction(numIni, numSub) {
  return parseFloat(numIni) - parseFloat(numSub);
}

//basic Multiplication
function multiply(numIni, numSub) {
  return parseFloat(numIni) * parseFloat(numSub);
}

//basic division
function divide(numIni, numSub) {
  return parseFloat(numIni) / parseFloat(numSub);
}

//operator function
function operate(op, numIni, numSub) {
  let result = 0;
  switch (op) {
    case "+":
      result = addition(numIni, numSub);
      break;
    case "-":
      result = subtraction(numIni, numSub);
      break;
    case "*":
      result = multiply(numIni, numSub);
      break;
    case "/":
      if (numSub == 0) {
        result = "Can't do that";
      } else {
        result = divide(numIni, numSub);
      }
      break;
    default:
      result = "Null";
  }
  return result;
}
//button display functions
function disNum(val) {
  parseFloat(display.value += val);
}

function disOp(val) {
  // Get last result
  let value = (res.value == '') ? '0' : res.value;
  // Search for valid operator stored previously
  let tmp = value.split('').pop();
  // Is it a valid previous operator?
  op = (['+', '-', '*', '/'].indexOf(tmp) == -1) ? '' : tmp;
  let numIni = parseFloat(value) || 0;
  let numSub = parseFloat(display.value) || 0;

  if(op == '') {
      // No previous operator
      if(res.value == "Can't do that" || res.value == 'Null') {
          res.value = '';
      } else if(display.value != '') {
          // Only if we have a value to show
          res.value = numSub;
      }
      // Don't add = as previous operator
      if(val != '=') {
          res.value += val;
      }
  } else if(display.value != '') {
      // Only do math if we have a value
      res.value = operate(op, numIni, numSub);
      // Don't add = as previous operator
      if(val != '=') {
          res.value += val;
      }
  }
  // Clear display, numIni will be taken from result
  display.value = '';
}

function clr() {
  res.value = '';
  display.value = '';
}
```

```css
input[type=text] {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<head>Calc</head>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="result" disabled placeholder="Result"><br>
  <input type="text" id="display">
</div>

<input type="button" value="1" onClick="disNum('1')">
<input type="button" value="2" onClick="disNum('2')">
<input type="button" value="3" onClick="disNum('3')">
<input type="button" value="+" onClick="disOp('+')"><br>
<input type="button" value="4" onClick="disNum('4')">
<input type="button" value="5" onClick="disNum('5')">
<input type="button" value="6" onClick="disNum('6')">
<input type="button" value="-" onClick="disOp('-')"><br>
<input type="button" value="7" onClick="disNum('7')">
<input type="button" value="8" onClick="disNum('8')">
<input type="button" value="9" onClick="disNum('9')">
<input type="button" value="*" onClick="disOp('*')"><br>
<input type="button" value="     0     " onClick="disNum('0')">
<input type="button" value="/" onClick="disOp('/')">
<input type="button" value="=" onClick="disOp('=')"><br>
<input type="button" value="Clear" onClick="clr()">
```

Comment: It is working now, but I need to now figure out how to add more than one number and operation, in order to string together several operations. I do see the display logic though that was a big help!

Comment: ` //if(numbers.length == 2) {
      numIni = numbers[0];
      numSub = numbers[1];
`

Comment: How would I get it to string operations together? ie: 12+7-5*3 @Triby

Comment: ok yea i've heard the dangers of eval(). So split the string inside the array?

Comment: I think i know what you're saying. Move the calculations into the swtich statement and return the result for each? or keep it how it is but have it return the result for each calculation?

Comment: this is definitely getting me closer to what i want. I just cant get it to do the correct Order of Operations @Triby