# How to make it so that previous answer is displayed when number is clicked after equals in js calculator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make it so that the previous result is displayed when the user presses a num after pressing equals... how do I do it? And just fyi I am just helping my friend make the code for his calculator clean - his was very messy - if you want I can show you his code as well.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='answer'>
      <p class='returnAnswer'>Answer Will Come Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class='buttonDiv'>
      <div class='button'>0</div>
      <div class='button'>1</div>
      <div class='button'>2</div>
      <div class='button'>3</div>
      <div class='button'>4</div>
      <div class='button'>5</div>
      <div class='button'>6</div>
      <div class='button'>7</div>
      <div class='button'>8</div>
      <div class='button'>9</div>
      <div class='equals'>=</div>
      <div class='button'>c</div>
      <div class='button'>+</div>
      <div class='button'>-</div>
      <div class='button'>x</div>
      <div class='button'>÷</div>
      <div class='button'>.</div>
      <div class='button'>%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
<script type="application/javascript" src="/share.js"></script>
<script>
  var eq = "";
  var ans = eval(eq);

  $('.button').click(function() {
    eq += $(this).text();
    $('.returnAnswer').text(eq);
  });
  $('.equals').click(function() {
    $('.returnAnswer').text(ans);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This is his code - view-source:https://leew.codewizardshq.com/OtherProjects/calculator/calculator.html

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140108/how-can-i-display-the-results-of-arithetics-operations-in-my-calculator/62140713#62140713

Comment: @Triby I really don't understand anything in that lol

Answer (score 0):

This was a fun thing to do.... Here is what I have done to your code

1. Added some styles to the button (not important, but makes it easier to click)
2. Added a class named num to each number button, that will be used to reset the display if any button is clicked following '=' button.
3. Removed 'equals' class from '=' button and added it as an ID
4. Added code to clear the display when 'C' is clicked
5. Changed buttons 'x' to ' * ' and '÷' to '/' as otherwise eval function will not work
6. **Changed back to 'x' and '÷', and added 2 lines inside `equals.clicked` to replace these with correct operators**

Check the Code snippet

```js
      var eq = "";
      var ans = eval(eq);
      var equalsCliked = false;

      $('.button').not("#equals, #cbutton").click(function () {

         if ($(this).hasClass('num') && equalsCliked)
            eq = "";
         eq += $(this).text();
         $('.returnAnswer').text(eq);
         equalsCliked = false;

      });

      $('#equals').click(function () {
         equalsCliked = true;
         eq = eq.split("÷").join("/");
         eq = eq.split("x").join("*");
         ans = eval(eq);
         eq = ans;
         $('.returnAnswer').text(ans);            
      });

      $('#cbutton').click(function () {
         equalsCliked = false;
         eq = "";
         ans = eval(eq);
         //eq = ans;
         $('.returnAnswer').text("");
      });
```

```css
      .button {
         border: 1px solid gray;
         padding: 8px;
         margin: 3px 3px;
         float: left;
         cursor: pointer;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
   <div class='container'>
      <div class='answer'>
         <p class='returnAnswer' style="width:330px; padding: 10px; min-height:20px; border: 1px solid gray; border-radius: 2px;">Answer Will Come Here</p>
      </div>
      <div class='buttonDiv' style="background-color:yellow; float:left; width: 330px;">
         <div class='button num'>0</div>
         <div class='button num'>1</div>
         <div class='button num'>2</div>
         <div class='button num'>3</div>
         <div class='button num'>4</div>
         <div class='button num'>5</div>
         <div class='button num'>6</div>
         <div class='button num'>7</div>
         <div class='button num'>8</div>
         <div class='button num'>9</div>
         <div id="equals" class='button'>=</div>
         <div id="cbutton" class='button'>C</div>
         <div class='button'>+</div>
         <div class='button'>-</div>
         <div class='button'>x</div>
         <div class='button'>÷</div>
         <div class='button'>.</div>
         <div class='button'>%</div>
      </div>
   </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Says 'Invalid or unexpected character' when I try to divide anything

Comment: Though my original answer had addressed your question, I have edited the answer to use these characters. However, for the calculator to work perfectly, there are other things you need to take care of like no operator at the end of the string, how to deal with % operator - whether this is a stand alone operator or part of equation? etc